# Azure SQL Bulk Insert text qualifier

Tags: sql, csv, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

It is 2018 and it seems importing text files into SQL isn't any smarter. 
I have a text file similar to this:

```
    "id","name","company","contract","notes"... 
    "234","Joe","conteso","pending","notes can have line feeds
 and/or carrage returns"
    "313","Ann","conteso",,"notes can have a , comma"
    "213","Ken",,,""
```

I have built a xml fmt file. 
With lines similar to

```
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
```

But as you can see I can't use "," as a delimiter since the " are optional if null. Also, I can't use just comma since the notes field could screw it up (there are columns after notes)

ANY idea how to parse this? .. I am loading from blob storage into azure SQL.

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

In short there is not way to do this with bulk insert.
The only way I was able to solve this was to change the powershell that created the source to use tab delimited and wrote a stored sproc to remove the leading and trailing double quotes from any column values that had them... just silly.. but needed to move past it..

-Ken